# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function | Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to improve a ticket bot with `Discord.js`, however I keep getting an error.

[image: Ref Image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is in images, which means it can't be searched by people who have the same question as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const createTicketChannel = async () => {
// ...
```

You can only use `await` in an `async` function